# Bimodal posterior distribution

Tags: distributions, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, bimodal

Do you know in which situations is it possible to have a bimodal posterior distribution for some parameters? 
I couldn't find any information on the web.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check for mixtures or non-identifiability

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think it could be possible to have a bimodal marginal posterior distribution of some parameters in the complete separation case fitting a Bayesian logistic regression?